# Append cookies and sending to next request using cookie manager in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing load test for my application. For login i am getting set-cookie in response headers. Is it possible to append all cookies using cookie manager and sending it in request header for another request

Answer (score 0):

Just add cookie manager to you thread group.

Jmeter will automatically transfer the cookies to the further request correspondingly

Comment: From my first request , response cookie is coming as  
 Set-cookie:Jsessionid=123456
 Set-cookie:User_Info = abc@test.com
 Set-cookie:Nsc_W=123456
But to my second request it has to append all the set-cookie and send as in request header but only the last cookie is sending with cookie manager

Comment: Those are not cookies. You have to do correlation and pass as parameters for further request.

Answer (score 0):

Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Thread Group, it should handle cookies automatically.

If it doesn't pick up all the cookies, there should be an issue with one or more cookies, i.e. [Domain or Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path) mismatch or [expiration date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) is in the past or whatever. If this is the case and you still want JMeter to consider the invalid cookies you can try adding the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

Given this property set to `false` JMeter won't check cookies before storing them and you should see "missing" ones, however I would recommend raising a defect against your application as the fact you are not seeing the cookies added by the HTTP Cookie Manager indicates that something is wrong with them